# $.post doesn't work but posting normally does

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page that I want to post some data when it opens

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post( "suggestions.php", { 'textbox': 'Yes'} );
```

obviously, the 'Yes' is just a placeholder for my testing, just to see if it posts anything. The weird thing is, when I post to a different php page it works, and when I post to "Suggestions.php" from a normal- non AJAX form

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once("php/connect.php"); 
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Try that</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='suggestions.php' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='textbox' value='Yes' />
        <button type='submit'>go!</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

it works, and yet, combined it doesn't.

Comment: And how do you know if it works/not works?

Comment: Define "works". What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? What does the Console in your browser's developer tools report? What does the Network tab in same report? Do you see the request being made? Do you see the response? Are they formatted as you expect? Does the response have a 200 OK status code?

Comment: The jQuery code (apart from missing `})`) should work with no problem. The problem must be related to your PHP code that you haven't posted it, i.e. the culprit is missing.

Comment: So I have this page that keeps refreshing and displays the "suggestions.php" page. If it would have worked it would have shown a mysql list generated according to the data posted.

Comment: "this page that keeps refreshing and displays the "suggestions.php" page" — So that's a different page to the one which the Ajax is running on?

Comment: What does the Console in your browser's developer tools report? What does the Network tab in same report? Do you see the request being made? Do you see the response? Are they formatted as you expect? Does the response have a 200 OK status code?

Comment: I looked in the console. The request is being made every 2.5 seconds but the preview is always "success":"false"... the page does have a 200OK status

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up switching to a GET method. The original page just sends the "textbox" info to a function that loads `suggestions.php?textbox= + e` on an interval.